# Real Analysis, Folland 3.4.26, Differentiation on Euclidean Space

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification

Background Information -  A Borel measure $\nu$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ will be called regular if

i.) $\nu(K) < \infty$ for every compact $K$

ii.) $\nu (E) = \inf\{\nu(U): E\subset U, U \ \text{open}\}$

We say that two signed measures $\mu$ and $\nu$ on $(X,M)$ are mutually singular if there exists $E,F\in M$ such that $E\cap F = \emptyset$, $E\cup F = X$, $E$ is null for $\mu$ and $F$ is null for $\nu$. We express this as $\mu\perp\nu$.

Problem 3.4.26 - If $\lambda$ and $\mu$ are positive, mutually singular Borel measures on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\lambda + \mu$ are regular, then so are $\lambda$ and $\mu$

Attempted proof: $\lambda\perp\mu$ then there exists $E,F\in M$ such that $E\cap F = \emptyset$, $E\cup F = X$, where $E$ is $\mu$-null and $F$ is $\lambda$-null.

Let $\nu = \lambda + \mu$. For compact $K\subset\mathbb{R}^n$, $\nu(K)<\infty$, and so $\lambda(K) < \infty$, $\mu(K) < \infty$ since $\lambda$ and $\mu$ are positive.

Let $F\in\mathbb{B}_{\mathbb{R}^n}$ so that $\mu(F) = \mu(F^c) = 0$. Then for all $E\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $$\lambda(F) = \lambda(F\cap E) = \nu(F\cap E) = \inf\{\nu(U):F\cap E\subset U, U \ \text{open}\}$$ Hence $\lambda,\mu$ are regular.

I am not sure if I am right, any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have shown that $\lambda(E)=\inf\{\nu(U): F\cap E\subset U, U \text{ open}\}$, but what you want to show is $\lambda(E)=\inf\{\lambda(U):  E\subset U, U \text{ open}\}$, so a gap remains.

Suggestion: Suppose that $\nu(E)<\infty$. If an open set $U$ contains $E$ and $\nu(U)\le\nu(E)+\epsilon$, then $\mu(U)<\infty$ and
$$
\lambda(U)=\nu(U)-\mu(U)\le\nu(E)-\mu(U)+\epsilon=\lambda(E)+[\mu(E)-\mu(U)]+\epsilon\le\lambda(E)+\epsilon.
$$
(The mutual singularity of $\lambda$ and $\mu$ appears to be a red herring.)

You can deal with the case $\nu(E)=\infty$ separately.

Comment: I see, so once I show $\lambda(E) = \inf\{\lambda(U): E\subset U, U \ \text{open}\}$ then I can confirm that $\lambda,\mu$ are regular?

Comment: That proves the regularity of $\lambda$,and that of $\mu$ follows in the same way.

Comment: ok, to understand you correctly your saying this proves regularity of $\lambda$. And $\mu$ follows in a similar fashion?

Comment: @Morgan Weiss Simply swapping $\lambda$ and $\mu$ gives you a proof for the regularity of $\mu$.

Comment: @JohnDawkins I didn't mean to deselect your answer, but I am having trouble with your suggestion. Is your suggestion a continuation of my proof or is it an alternative approach?

Comment: It is a re-direction of your argument.

Comment: So is $\nu$ defined in the same manner that I defined it?

Comment: Yes, I was using your notation.